# BootstrapVue collapses with open and close all buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

This has been troubling me for some time now.

Can someone please help me figure out how to build multiple BootstrapVue collapses that open and close individually. In fact, the opening and closing individually already works, as that comes out of the box. I'd like the Open and Close all buttons to open all or close all collapses when pressed at any point.

https://codepen.io/akolinski/pen/ZNKraN

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  showCollapse: false
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2">
      
         <h1>Vue with BootstrapVue collapse and open and close all buttons</h1>
         <p class="lead">The purpose of this pen is to build multiple BootstrapVue collapses that open and close individually. However we want the Open and Close all buttons to open all or close or collapses when pressed.</p>
         <hr>

         <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button class="mr-2" @click="showCollapse = true">Open all</b-button>
               <b-button @click="showCollapse = false">Close all</b-button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse 1</b-button>
               <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
                  <b-card>
                     <p class="card-text">Collapse 1 contents Here</p>
                  </b-card>
               </b-collapse>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-2 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse 2</b-button>
               <b-collapse id="collapse-2" class="mt-2">
                  <b-card>
                     <p class="card-text">Collapse 2 contents Here</p>
                  </b-card>
               </b-collapse>
            </div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-3 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse 3</b-button>
               <b-collapse id="collapse-3" class="mt-2">
                  <b-card>
                     <p class="card-text">Collapse 3 contents Here</p>
                  </b-card>
               </b-collapse>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kind of a work around, forgive me, but you could programmatically assign the collapsible buttons an id, and use `querySelectorAll` to fetch the elements id and click on them  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYMjRB this has some edge cases but it might put you towards the right path.

Comment: @KevinHernandez I had something similar. The difficulty with that is that if an individual collapse is already open then it will close. I need to tell it to just toggle opening of all the collapses, not matter if they are already open or closed.

Comment: Ok well then give each of the buttons a `v-model` and set that to false by default, if the button is clicked then it will be set to true, true means the collapse menu is in view. In the code that i showed you, while you are iterating through each of the elements, if the current elements `v-model` is true or false(whatever you want), then skip that element and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the BootstrapVue community on discord. We came up with this CodePen to show the correct functionality.

Credit: Hiws#0325

https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/MdvPEX

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  collapses: [ 
     { show: false },
     { show: false },
     { show: false }
  ]
 },
 methods: {
    openAll() {
       this.collapses.forEach(collapse => {
          collapse.show = true
       })
    },
    closeAll() {
       this.collapses.forEach(collapse => {
          collapse.show = false
       })
    }
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2">
         <h1>Vue with BootstrapVue collapse and open and close all buttons</h1>
         <p class="lead">The purpose of this pen is to build multiple BootstrapVue collapses that open and close individually. However we want the Open and Close all buttons to open all or close or collapses when pressed.</p>
         <hr>

         <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button class="mr-2" @click="openAll">Open all</b-button>
               <b-button @click="closeAll">Close all</b-button>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row mb-4" v-for="(collapse, index) in collapses" :key="index">
            <div class="col-12">
               <b-button @click="collapse.show = !collapse.show" variant="primary">Toggle Collapse {{ index + 1 }}</b-button>
               <b-collapse v-model="collapse.show" id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
                  <b-card>
                     <p class="card-text">Collapse {{ index + 1 }} contents Here</p>
                  </b-card>
               </b-collapse>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```